# .NET Inheritance/Interfaces

Tags: .net, vb.net, inheritance

How to access inherited property in Generic Method?

```
Public Sub DoSomething(Of BusObjectType)(MyBusObject As BusObjectType)

    MyBusObject.Property1 = "Something"

End Sub
```

Property1 is inherited from a base class. I don't have an interface, just a base class for all my business objects.

Answer (score 2):

You can add an `As BaseClassName` to the generic definition to ensure that what ever it is will be of that base type.

For example:

```
Public Sub DoSomething(Of BusObjectType As BaseClassName)(MyBusObject As BusObjectType)

    MyBusObject.Property1 = "Something"

End Sub
```

See here ("Constraints" section) for more information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w256ka79.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If this is *all* you are doing, then the method doesn't need to be generic:

```
Public Sub DoSomething(MyBusObject As {base class})

    MyBusObject.Property1 = "Something"

End Sub
```

You only need to make it generic if you are *returning* the value and want it to be typed properly, or calling another generic method that requires the specific type.  You can pass a derived class as a parameter that is typed as the base class.

For example:

```
Public Sub Feed(pet As Animal)

    // feed the pet

End Sub
```

You can pass in a `Dog`, a `Cat`, or a `Ferret` (if that's your sort of thing).  You don't need to have different methods for each pet type or make the method generic.